# Prove that the number $3^{3^n} + 1$ has at least $2n + 1$ prime factors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

For any natural $n,$ prove that $3^{3^n} + 1$ has at least $2n + 1$ prime factors.

My idea was to use induction:

- for $n = 1$:
  $$f(1) = 3^3 + 1 = 28 = 7*2^2$$
- let it be true for $n = k$, then for $n = k + 1$:
  $$f(k + 1) = 3^{3^{k + 1}} + 1 = 3^{3*3^k} + 1 = (3^{3^k} + 1)(3^{2*3^k} - 3^{3^k} + 1) = f(k)\times(3^{2*3^k} - 3^{3^k} + 1)$$

Now I have a problem:   how to prove that $(3^{2*3^k} - 3^{3^k} + 1)$ is not a prime number?

Or, if it is harder than solving the original problem, please give a hint where I turned the wrong way.

Comment: We can show there are atleast $n$ distinct prime divisors. Using the gcd =1.

Comment: @taritgoswami Yes, thanks, it makes the task wider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\large(3^{2\times3^k} - 3^{3^k} + 1) = (3^{3^k}-3^{(3^k+1)/2}+1)(3^{3^k}+3^ {(3^k+1)/2}+1)$$

Comment: [Aurifeuillean_factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization)

Comment: Cf. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173610/number-theory-divisibility-check-question/3173640#3173640)

Comment: Thank you. Never heard about this.

Comment: Examples of the link you left for the two terms, how to get the factorization for the three?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; does [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AurifeuilleanFactorization.html) explain it?

Comment: I'm asking where can I find explanation how to get this formula. It's not obvious for me(

Answer (score 4):

We have:
$$3^{2\cdot3^k} - 3^{3^k} + 1=(3^{3^k}+3^{\frac{3^k+1}{2}}+1)(3^{3^k}-3^{\frac{3^k+1}{2}}+1)$$
And for $k>0$ both factors are greater than one. This factorization can be deduced from the fact that $f(2)=387400807=19441\cdot19927$ and that both factors are close to each other.